# finding a function whose values at certain points are defined

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions

I have certain polynomials in a sequence from which I am trying to derive the common term. The polynomials are:

$7k^2-8\\ 21k^4-368k^2-704\\ 42k^6-1424k^4+8576k^2+74752\\70k^8-3520k^6+49920k^4+61440k^2-4136960 $

To see the problem more clearly, I have written them in form of summation as:

$\sum\limits_{n=1}^p f(n,p)k^{2n}+g(p)$ where $p=1,2,3,4 $ represents the first, second, third and fourth polynomials respectively.

Here $f(n,p)$ satisfies the following conditions:

$f(1,1)=7$,

$f(1,2)=-368$, $f(2,2)=21$

$f(1,3)=8576$, $f(2,3)=-1424$, $f(3,3)=42$

$f(1,4)=61440$, $f(2,4)=49920$, $f(3,4)=-3520$, $f(4,4)=70$

and

$g(1)=-8$, $g(2)=-704$, $g(3)=74752$, $g(4)=-4136960$

So far I have only been able to figure out that:

$f(p,p)=\frac{7p(p+1)}{2}$

If, let us say, we have found f(n,p) and g(p), then surprisingly the following result seems to hold.

\begin{equation}
192\sum\limits_{p=1}^{\infty}\frac{k^{2p-2}(\sum\limits_{n=1}^p f(n,p)k^{2n}+g(p))}{{(k^2-24)}^{p}{(k^2-8)}^{p+2}}=-\frac{1}{8} 
\end{equation}
in a given range of $k$ seems to hold.

I have checked this for some given values of $k$ and it seems to be true. This gives me the feeling that the $f(n,p)$ and $g(p)$ follow some kind of pattern in some kind of an already known series. Can somebody help me figure this out?

Comment: If only $4$ elements of a sequence are given, there are many possible formulas for the whole sequence.

Comment: Can you give me any two such fomulae and also how you approached the problem?

Comment: You can, for example, calculate the interpolating polynomial.

Comment: This gives $g(p)=-727220p^3 + 4401396p^2 - 8114344p + 4440160$

Comment: How to approach $f(n,p)$?

Comment: This is more difficult because I do not know how to interpolate a polynomial with $2$ unknowns.

Comment: $g(p)=-555020/3p^4 + 3368540/3p^3 - 6221512/3p^2 + 3407968/3p$ is another possibility for $g(p)$ which contains the origin as well.

Comment: For $f(n,p)$, it is probably best to interpolate for each $n$ or for each $p$, depending what you prefer.

Comment: Are the polynomials random or do they come from a specific problem ?

Comment: They come from a problem of the Mathieu equation and applying variational iteration method to it. The thing is I can compute to only 4 terms but beyond that it is far too time consuming. But I can compute up to 30 terms if I give $k$ some value. Would that help?

Comment: I do not think that it would help. And the interpolations I mentioned are useless for further values. Alas, I have no experience with mathieu equations.

Comment: Please check the update. I have a strong feeling that these polynomials follow some kind of pattern in an already known series (bessel, hypergeometric) etc. but can't seem to figure out.